# Custom intent to other app

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a simple question but i can't find anything on google, maybe i use the wrong key word.

I'm developping an app with a service in background. This service is always started. I have a phone with a custom button than can start an app. But i want to use this button to start an action on my service don't start any activity.

To do that, i have think about an ugly solution : I configure my custom button to start an other app. This app is a blanck activity and on the onCreate() event i just send an itent to my service and after finish the activity.

My question is how can i send a custom intent to an other app ?
my idea : in the blanck activity write this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
   super.onCreate();
   Intent customIntent = new Intent("com.customIntent.action");
   startActivity(customIntent);
   finish();
}
```

On my service doing something like that :

```
IntentFilter it = new IntentFilter();
it.addAction("com.customIntent.action");
registerReceiver(myReceiver, it);
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does service starts before `Activity` or `Activity` starts before `service`?

Comment: My service is always start with the android boot so my service will be always here to catch the intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering `receiver` and it will only be catched when `sendBroadCast` will be called with the intent. Secondly, you are starting `Activity` with that `Intent` action. There is no `Activity` in xml/code which handles this action. Thirdly, you can add this `Intent Filter` in `AndroidManifest` against specific reciever and in `Activity` use

```
Intent customIntent = new Intent("com.customIntent.action");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(customIntent);
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name="." >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.customIntent.action" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `LocalBroadcastManager` for *send a custom intent to an other app* ... interesting choice ... hehehe

Comment: This doesn't work actually, My service is running on my APP1, with my second app i just want to send an intent to this service. The LocalBroadcastManager don't do the link.

Comment: Are you registering Receiver in AndroidManifest? Please post your AndroidManifest and your SErviec code

Comment: To solve that i have used a sendBroadcast on my first application and a very simple intentfilter and broadcastListener on my second one.

Answer (score -1):

I dont't know if I understand your question correctly but this tutorial explains very well how you use an intent to interact with another app:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html

Comment: This can't do the job because i don't want to choose something i just want to send it automatically. If you know how to do it great !